# Cannot figure out how to use 'FORFILES' to delete files only in sub/directories of 'WIP' folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I cannot figure out how to get 'FORFILES' to delete files with a '.bak' extension that are 3 years old AND have it only look within sub/directories that are a WIP folder.

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

forfiles /P "Y:\Africa" /S /M *.bak /D -1095 /C "cmd /c Del @path"
ECHO                      AFRICA - COMPLETED
Echo.
forfiles /P "Y:\Asia" /S /M *.bak /D -1095 /C "cmd /c Del @path"
ECHO                        ASIA - COMPLETED
Echo.
forfiles /P "Y:\Australia" /S /M *.bak /D -1095 /C "cmd /c Del @path"
ECHO                  AUSTRAILIA - COMPLETED
Echo.
forfiles /P "Y:\Europe" /S /M *.bak /D -1095 /C "cmd /c Del @path"
ECHO                      EUROPE - COMPLETED
Echo.
forfiles /P "Y:\North America\Canada" /S /M *.bak /D -1095 /C "cmd /c Del @path"
ECHO                      CANADA - COMPLETED
Echo.
forfiles /P "Y:\North America\Mexico" /S /M *.bak /D -1095 /C "cmd /c Del @path"
ECHO                      MEXICO - COMPLETED
Echo.
forfiles /P "Y:\North America\United States" /S /M *.bak /D -1095 /C "cmd /c Del @path"
ECHO               UNITED STATES - COMPLETED
Echo.
forfiles /P "Y:\South America" /S /M *.bak /D -1095 /C "cmd /c Del @path"
ECHO               SOUTH AMERICA - COMPLETED
Echo.
Pause
Goto :Selection
```

Currently the code is going into EVERY folder. searching for EVERY '.bak' file older than 3 years in each sub/directory. But I only wish for it to ONLY look in folders and its sub/directories if the folder is called WIP just to shave off half an hour from the scripts run time.

There is nothing to be deleted that applies to these criteria outside of the WIP folders as OTHER codes in the utility I am writing already take care of ‘.bak’ files in folders such as MASTERS (which we do not care if they are 3 years old or not, ‘.bak’ does not belong in there anyway nor is needed). However, if there IS something outside of the WIP folder that would apply to the criteria already set in the code, if its LOCKED (which we do not do for WIP folder files), it locks up the script and hangs at "Access is denied"...)

I will give an example 
Africa has:

```
Y:\Africa\Egypt\wip
Y:\Africa\Kenya\WIP
Y:\Africa\South Africa\WIP
```

Asia has its many folders with individual countries like Africa has EXCEPT china has 4 folders that have WIP folders inside.
Many of folders labeled regionally are set up like this. 
Is it possible to go into each path and skip into a sub/directory until it hits a WIP folder? like a '%%A wildcard' or something like you can do with 'FOR'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a mechanism to check that the current working directory ends in `wip`.  There are a few different ways to do this but I chose to use a `FOR /D /R` command and then check to see if the child directory is equal to `wip`.

```
@echo off
for /d /r %%G in (wip*) do IF /I "%%~nxG"=="wip" (
    PUSHD "%%G"
    forfiles /M *.bak /D -1095 /C "cmd /c Del @path"
    popd
)
```

You can put this in the root of your Y: drive and it will only process the directories that end in wip

### **EDIT:**

If you can't run the batch file from the root directory of where you data is there are three ways to make the script change to a different directory.

If you just want to change to a different drive letter, you specify the driver letter with the colon

```
 Y:
```

You can also use the `CD` command. Short for change directory.

```
CD mydirectory
```

If you need to change the directory and the drive letter at the same time you need to use the `/D` option with the `CD` command.

```
CD /D Y:\mydirecotry
```

And last but not least because it is my favorite way to do this is to use the `PUSHD` command.

```
PUSHD Y:\somedirectory
```

But if you use the `PUSHD` command you then need to use a `POPD` command to return to the original directory.  Just like I am using in the code.

Comment: Due to how things are with the company we are working for, we cannot place things in the root of the Drive.

Is there any way to do this so that the Batch Code can be run from someones desktop or even from a folder on another drive?

Comment: @Daggerfella Run it from anywhere you want.  I was just making a suggestion.

Comment: I ran the code and it didnt work. i put a file with a date modified/created date of 1/19/1980 in the folder "Y:\Africa\South Africa\WIP\GMSA - Aloes\Site\26867-IMP" and it didnt delete the file. I am guess since its not in the root folder thats why its not finding them. im guessing i should to For /D /R %%G in ("Y:\Folder Name\*.*") Do IF /I "%%~nxG=="wip" (

Comment: @Daggerfella, look at your `FORFILES` command and look at mine.  What did I miss?  Considering doing a little debugging on your own before asking more questions.  I forgot the `/S` in the FORFILES command.

Comment: Okay i did it like this:

 for /d /r %%G in (wip*) do IF /I "%%~nxG"=="wip" (
    PUSHD "%%G"
    forfiles /P "Y:\Africa" /S /M *.bak /D -1095 /C "cmd /c Del @path"
    popd
)

 and its deleting files from the MASTERS folders.
I did it like this:

for /d /r %%G in (wip*) do IF /I "%%~nxG"=="wip" (
    PUSHD "%%G"
    forfiles /S /M *.bak /D -1095 /C "cmd /c Del @path"
    popd
)

and it did nothing just like when i tried this: 

for /d /r %%G in ("Y:\Africa") do IF /I "%%~nxG"=="wip" (
    PUSHD "%%G"
    forfiles /S /M *.bak /D -1095 /C "cmd /c Del @path"
    popd
)

Comment: @Daggerfella, do NOT put that much code in a comment.  It is not readable by any chance.

Comment: i don't think its my fault that i cannot enter a new line on stack overflows comments...

Comment: @Daggerfella, all you needed to do was use my existing code and add the `/S` to `FORFILES`.  All three of your code changes were incorrect which tells me you are not learning how any of the code works.

Comment: and i just said i tried your exact code with the "/S" put where it belongs and it didnt delete anything at all, not in WIP, not in master, not even in the root directory. its finding NOTHING at all...

Comment: @Daggerfella, ok.  The proof is in the pudding.  I will post my input and output testing that I am using to prove to you that the code works. Where in any of your previous comments did you say you used my exact code with the /S?

Comment: did it like this: 

for /d /r %%G in (wip) do IF /I "%%~nxG"=="wip" ( PUSHD "%%G" forfiles /S /M *.bak /D -1095 /C "cmd /c Del @path" popd ) 

and it did nothing.

I said it above in the comment that says 23 minutes ago that you said was not readable by any chance. If its not working on my end and getting to the Y:\ drive when run from my desktop then how will it work on your end?

Comment: I know some basics and ive written code before, im self taught and i only learn what i need as its needed. i have no text book or resource other than online sources that barely expand upon what microsoft puts down when you do /? after a command. so im sorry if you think im not learning from all of this, its not like ive gone to school or have been doing this my whole life. i only started doing batch files last year and other than that ive no script experience outside of ACS

Comment: That is not my exact code.  In my free time I will run the script and post my output.  I will even create a Y: drive on my server.

Comment: no it is the same code, only difference is that i added in the /S you didnt include and the @Echo Off. Remember how i said i ran it as it and it did nothing? also sorry for the typo, i typed it all out, meant to say (wip*)m i tried it again. ill even send a screen cap it IS the same code ffs, just cuz its missing the /s you said ya forgot (and claimed it wasnt working cuz it was missing it)  https://i.imgur.com/TfEwz8F.png

Comment: @Daggerfella Turn `ECHO ON` at the top of the script.  Open up a command prompt and run the script from the command prompt instead of running it with your mouse. Describe what is happening.

Comment: its going to old test locations ive archived on the C Drive and not the Y Drive.

Comment: Where are you running the script from?

Comment: from my desktop. you said i could run it from there and not the root directory of the Y Drive. which is why i asked where i could specify the path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183251/discussion-between-squashman-and-daggerfella).

Comment: Thanks, i didnt think of that